# Extracting numbering of bullets with regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to select numbers which are at the starting of the line and end with a dot. Examples are as follows:

```
1. Samish I, Macdermaid CM, Perez-Aguilar JM, Saven
JG (2011) Theoretical and computational protein
design. Annu Rev Phys Chem 62:129–149.


2. Kiss G, C¸elebi- €Olc¸€um N, Moretti R, Baker D, Houk KN
(2013) Computational enzyme design. Angew Chem Int
Ed Engl 52:5700–5725.


3. Ghadessy FJ, Ong JL, Holliger P (2001) Directed evo-
lution of polymerase function by compartmentalized
self-replication. Proc Natl Acad Sci USA 98:4552–4557.
4. Cauchy M, D’Aoust S, Dawson B, Rode H, Hefford MA
(2002) Thermal stability: a means to assure tertiary
structure in therapeutic proteins. Biologicals 30:175–
185.
```

The result should be as follows: `1. 2. 3. 4.`

I am using the following regex `[^/]\d\.` However, all numbers ending with a dot are getting selected as well. Could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you use the `^` at the beginning of the regex which only matches the beginning of the line?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I tried different combinations. I am still a beginner. Sorry for my ignorance

Comment: I didn't downvote it, for your information. That comment was basically the solution, which is already reflected in an answer.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Sorry about that

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I am really sorry for my silly outburst. it is just that  don't understand why people downvote and not provide reasons for doing so. I don't need so much reputation. but if i lose reputation, i lose the right to ask more questions. At least I need an opportunity to improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this regex in `MULTILINE` mode:

```
^\d+\.
```

Your regex `[^/]\d\.` on the other hand means a non-slash followed by a single digit followed by a DOT.

Comment: hi i am trying in pythex but only the first number is getting

Comment: Make sure you use `MULTILINE` mode